# Undefined reading JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I got this code to get a json object, this works.

```
$.getJSON("http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/artists/" + artist_id + "/calendar.json?apikey=Key&jsoncallback=?", function callback(json) {

    $.each(json["resultsPage"], function (i, entry) {
        alert(entry.totalEntries);
    });
});
```

When I execute the code I get this when there's no data about an artist:

```
?({"resultsPage":{"results":{},"totalEntries":0,"perPage":50,"page":1,"status":"ok"}})
```

What I want is to get the value of the totalEntries to validate if there is some data but I keep getting UNDEFINED. I'm using the alert to show the value.

What could be the problem, or a better way to get totalEntries or validate if the query bings something.

A good one (When Finds something):

```
{"resultsPage":{"results":{"artist":[{"uri":"http:\/\/www.songkick.com\/artists\/462022-britney-spears?utm_source=11548&utm_medium=partner","displayName":"Britney Spears","id":462022,"onTourUntil":null,"identifier":[{"href":"http:\/\/api.songkick.com\/api\/3.0\/artists\/mbid:45a663b5-b1cb-4a91-bff6-2bef7bbfdd76.json","eventsHref":"http:\/\/api.songkick.com\/api\/3.0\/artists\/mbid:45a663b5-b1cb-4a91-bff6-2bef7bbfdd76\/calendar.json","mbid":"45a663b5-b1cb-4a91-bff6-2bef7bbfdd76","setlistsHref":"http:\/\/api.songkick.com\/api\/3.0\/artists\/mbid:45a663b5-b1cb-4a91-bff6-2bef7bbfdd76\/setlists.json"}]},{"uri":"http:\/\/www.songkick.com\/artists\/5034848-hits-of-pink-christina-aguilera-britney-spears-and-motley-crue?utm_source=11548&utm_medium=partner","displayName":"Hits of Pink, Christina Aguilera, Britney Spears and M\u00f6tley Cr\u00fce","id":5034848,"onTourUntil":null,"identifier":[]},{"uri":"http:\/\/www.songkick.com\/artists\/2885106-kimberly-dale-as-britney-spears?utm_source=11548&utm_medium=partner","displayName":"Kimberly Dale As Britney Spears","id":2885106,"onTourUntil":null,"identifier":[]}]},"totalEntries":3,"perPage":50,"page":1,"status":"ok"}}
```

Comment: Deleted my comment because it was rubbish. Just now remembered that this might in fact be JSONP

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over the fields of "resultsPage", not over "resultsPage" itself. I think what you meant was:

```
alert(json.resultsPage.totalEntries); // Without the "each", you don't need it
```

Test it yourself, change your code to

```
$.each(json["resultsPage"], function (i, entry) {
    alert([i, entry]);
});
```

and it will alert (in no particular order):

```
results, [object Object]
totalEntries, 0
perPage, 50
page, 1
status, ok
```